# can't add double forward slashes on exec function php

Tags: php, wmic

Currently I have this problem in PHP, I am trying to make a simple webpage that executes some code in the shell and shows the proccess running
the code I am trying to execute is this

```
wmic -U User%Passwd //192.168.1.3 "select Caption from Win32_Process"
```

In the shell it executes correctly (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) but in PHP those double slashes are taken as a comment, like in this code

```
exec('wmic -U User%Passwd //'.$IP.' "select Caption from Win32_Process"',$exit);
```

However, the double forward slashes (//) are commenting the rest of the code!

How can I rewrite that code in order for PHP to interpret those double slashes not as a comment but as part of the code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess you need to escape them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the slash `/` char with backslash char `\`, so your new code will be:

```
exec('wmic -U User%Passwd \/\/'.$IP.' "select Caption from Win32_Process"',$exit);
```

From PHP manual:

> The backslash character has several uses. Firstly, if it is followed
>   by a non-alphanumeric character, it takes away any special meaning
>   that character may have. This use of backslash as an escape character
>   applies both inside and outside character classes.
>
> For example, if you want to match a "*" character, you write "*" in
>   the pattern. This applies whether or not the following character would
>   otherwise be interpreted as a meta-character, so it is always safe to
>   precede a non-alphanumeric with "\" to specify that it stands for
>   itself. In particular, if you want to match a backslash, you write
>   "\".